# How to get the custom attribute of a const string contained in struct in static class

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I search a solution to get the custom attribute of a const string by the value of this const string. Like this example :

```
public static class Directory
{
    public struct Bank01
    {
        [SymbolAttribute("Attribute01")]
        public const string Value01 = "Bank01.Value01";
        [SymbolAttribute("Attribute02")]
        public const string Value02 = "Bank01.Value02";
    }
    public struct Bank02
    {
        [SymbolAttribute("Attribute03")]
        public const string Value01 = "Bank02.Value01";
        [SymbolAttribute("Attribute04")]
        public const string Value02 = "Bank02.Value02";
    }


    public static SymbolAttribute GetSymbolAttribute(string value)
    {
        return typeof(Directory)
            .GetMember(value.Split('.')[0])
            .GetType()
            .GetField(value.Split('.')[1])
            .GetCustomAttribute<SymbolAttribute>();
    }
}
```

I want use this function like this :

```
public static Main()
    {
        SymbolAttribute attribute = GetSymbolAttribute(Directory.Bank01.Value01);
    }
```

I don't understand why this one work :

```
return typeof(Directory.Bank01)
            .GetField(value.Split('.')[1])
            .GetCustomAttribute<SymbolAttribute>();
```

And this one doesn't work :

```
return typeof(Directory)
            .GetMember(value.Split('.')[0])
            .GetType()
            .GetField(value.Split('.')[1])
            .GetCustomAttribute<SymbolAttribute>();
```

Do you have an idea ? Thank you in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bank01` and `Bank02` are not members, they are nested classes, so you should use `GetNestedType` instead.

```
typeof(Directory)
    .GetNestedType(value.Split('.')[0])
    .GetField(value.Split('.')[1])
    .GetCustomAttribute<SymbolAttribute>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I've already tried with Properties, Members, Fields and NestedType but this one not work.. The problem is the usage of ".GetType()", if I replace this one by ".UnderlyingSystemType" everythings work fine ! But why this one doesn't work with GetType() an idea ?

Comment: Have you still keep `.GetType()`? If so remove it.

Comment: Ok I'm just stupid, it's already a Type after  .GetNestedType()?  thank you shingo !